# Creating a dynamic column of JSON values in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working in T-SQL with Azure SQL Data Warehouse and trying to create a column of JSON values from the columns of another table. The desired result is this type of structure:

| Name | json_row |
| --- | --- |
| Jake | {'birthday':2000-01-01,'age':23,'fav_colour':red,'cats_owned':2} |
| Phil | {'birthday':2003-03-04,'age':20,'fav_colour':green,'dogs_owned':1} |

I am able to get to a state where the JSON contains values for all keys

eg: {'birthday':2000-01-01,'age':23,'fav_colour':red,'cats_owned':2, 'dogs_owned':0}

But I want to get to a state where the key-value pairs are excluded if the value is 0 (like in the table above)

I have the following logic so far:

```
SELECT 
  name
,'{' + '"birthday": "' + COALESCE(CAST(birthday AS VARCHAR),'Unknown') + '",' +
        '"age": ' + COALESCE(age,'Unknown') + ',' +
        '"fav_colour": ' + COALESCE(red,'Unknown') + ',' +
        CASE WHEN SUM(cat_qty) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(cat_qty) <> 0 THEN '"cats_owned": ' + COALESCE(CAST(SUM(cat_qty) AS VARCHAR),'0') + ',' END +
        CASE WHEN SUM(dog_qty) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(dog_qty) <> 0 THEN '"dogs_owned": ' + COALESCE(CAST(SUM(dog_qty) AS VARCHAR),'0') + ','  END +
        '}'AS json_row

FROM Table
GROUP BY name, birthday, age, fav_colour
```

However, this produces NULL values for every row in the json_row column. I should also add that it is possible for cat_qty and dog_qty to be NULL, hence the COALESCE statements.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `FOR JSON`? All supported SQL Server versions support JSON

Answer (score 2):

The NULL values in the json_row column might be caused by missing quotes around the string values in the JSON construction. Also, I see that the condition for excluding key-value pairs when the value is 0 is not correctly implemented.

```
SELECT 
  name,
  (
    SELECT 
      'birthday:' + COALESCE('"' + CAST(birthday AS VARCHAR) + '"','"Unknown"') + ',' +
      'age:' + COALESCE(CAST(age AS VARCHAR), '0') + ',' +
      'fav_colour:' + COALESCE('"' + fav_colour + '"','"Unknown"') + ',' +
      CASE WHEN SUM(cat_qty) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(cat_qty) <> 0 THEN 'cats_owned:' + COALESCE(CAST(SUM(cat_qty) AS VARCHAR), '0') + ',' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN SUM(dog_qty) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(dog_qty) <> 0 THEN 'dogs_owned:' + COALESCE(CAST(SUM(dog_qty) AS VARCHAR), '0') + ',' ELSE '' END
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE name = t.name
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) AS json_row
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY name, birthday, age, fav_colour;
```